# Add WHERE with IN and OR to a product collection

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product-collection, query

I want to add something like `WHERE (table1.attrib1 IN (1,2,3) OR table2.attrib2 IN (1,2,3))` to a product collection to which I have already joined a couple of tables.

I tried this, but it doesn't work because it took '1,2,3' as one string (that is, did not put them in brackets after IN). How can I use WHERE?

```
$productCollection->getSelect()->join(array('table1' => $table1), 'e.entity_id = table1.entity_id', array('my_attribute1' => 'table1.value'))->join(array('table2' => $table2), 'e.entity_id = table2.entity_id', array('my_attribute2' => 'table2.value'))->where('table1.attrib1 IN ? OR table2.attrib2 IN ? ', '1,2,3')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try it this way

```
// ...
->where('table1.attrib1 IN (?) OR table2.attrib2 IN (?) ', array(1,2,3));
```

Wrap the placeholders in parenthesis `(?)` and provide the values as an array `array(1,2,3)` instead of the former string.

Answer (score 4):

How to use joinTable is described here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13267/217

and in more details here: http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/joining-a-flat-table-on-eav/

To use in in a filter you can use:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('attrib', array('in' => array(1,2,3))
```

and to use or you have to use the arrays recursive, like this:

```
$in = array('in' => array(1,2,3));
$in2 = array('in' => array(4,5,6));
->addAttributeToFilter('attrib', array($in, $in2)
```

should create:

```
WHERE attrib IN (1,2,3) OR attrib IN (4,5,6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the solution  ,if want to filter a collection by it field then use  `addFieldTofilter() function ,which is applicable for non-eav collection and eav collection.`

if you  filter  a collection by in then used below logic and code

```
$collection->addFieldTofilter('field_name', array(
    'in' => array($val1, $val2, $val3),
    ));
```

If you  filter product collection then used `addAttribuetToFilter('')`

for a exmaple

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('field_name', array(
    'in' => array(1, 2, 3),
    ));
```

More details on 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento